# Brick ID on the Mega Bloks - round building in 2 parts with door and window

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

please help with ID on the following parts. Would like to know set and eventually instructions. The Door has AM17450 on it and looks like Pego or something similar Copyright inside on yellow.

Would make a 5 year old very happy. Many thanks in advance.

[image: Mega Bloks - round building in 2 parts with door and window]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Papa Smurf's House](https://www.megabrands.com/en-us/shop/smurfs/papa-smurfs-house-10752), but there may be many houses in that line. Do you have anything else from that set that could narrow it down?

[image: Papa Smurf's House]